# R - Left join based on the next largest value

Tags: r, join

I am looking to join a table to my dataset based on between which 2 values it falls. It should preferably work within a dplyr pipe. The datasets look as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(01,02,03,04,05,06), result = c(0.33,0,-2.11,3.33,4.44,-7.1))
key <- data.frame(upper_value = c(-4,-1,1,4,10), points = c(0,1,2,3,4))
```

The lowest value of *result* can be 10, but as I am searching for next largest (or equal) value, it is not mentioned in the *key* dataset.

Take note that the results do not have to be integers.

The expected result looks like this:

```
expected <- data.frame(ID = c(01,02,03,04,05,06), result = c(0.3333,0,-2.11,3.3333,4.44,-7.1), c(2,2,1,3,4,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fuzzy_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package -

```
library(dplyr)

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(data, key, by = c('result' = 'upper_value'), 
                           match_fun = `<`) %>%
  arrange(ID, upper_value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup

#  ID result upper_value points
#  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1   0.33           1      2
#2     2   0              1      2
#3     3  -2.11          -1      1
#4     4   3.33           4      3
#5     5   4.44          10      4
#6     6  -7.1           -4      0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks good. What would the solution be if I wanted to join on 2 columns, one being an exact match and the other being `<`?

Comment: If the columns that you want to check for exact match is `ID`, change `by` to `by = c('ID', 'result' = 'upper_value')` and `match_fun` to `match_fun = c(\`==\`, \`<\`)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `findInterval`

```
data$new <- findInterval(data$result, key$upper_value)
```

-output

```
data
#  ID result new
#1  1   0.33   2
#2  2   0.00   2
#3  3  -2.11   1
#4  4   3.33   3
#5  5   4.44   4
#6  6  -7.10   0
```

---

With this example, the 'points' is the same as the index.  In case, it is different

```
data$new <- key$points[findInterval(data$result, key$upper_value) + 1]
```